# Pascal theorem\ Binomial Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$$
\text{For the general power sum: } S_n^p:=1^p+2^p+3^p...n^p
$$
$$
\text{Show that: }(p+1)S_n^p + {p+1\choose 2}S_n^{p-1} + {p+1\choose 3}S_n^{p-2}+...+S_n^0=(n+1)^{p+1}-1
$$

A part of the answer is:

$$
(p+1)S_n^p + {p+1\choose 2}S_n^{p-1} + {p+1\choose 3}S_n^{p-2}+...+S_n^0=(p+1)[1^p+2^p+...+n^p]+{p+1\choose2}[1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+...+n^{p-1}]+...+1*[1^0+2^0+...+n^0]$$$$=\sum_{k=0}^{p}1^k{p+1 \choose k}+\sum_{k=0}^{p}2^k{p+1 \choose k}+...+\sum_{k=0}^{p}n^k{p+1 \choose k}
$$
I cant understand how come that when the first two elements of the sum are:
$$
\text{I.} (p+1)S_n^p + {p+1\choose 2}S_n^{p-1}...
$$
It can be rewritten to:
$$
\text{II.}\sum_{k=0}^{p}1^k{p+1 \choose k}+\sum_{k=0}^{p}2^k{p+1 \choose k}{...}
$$
and so on..
How come that in II we can have k=1 but in I k starts as 0 and afterwards it is 2 and so on?

Comment: See the answer of Cavalieri [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2441119)

Comment: See as well [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338249827_Sums_of_Powers_of_Consecutive_Integers_and_Pascal%27s_Triangle).